# wifi problems in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, wireless, versions, additional-drivers

In ubuntu there is no option for  wifi display .I saw your previous answers but here in my ubuntu the coulumn of additional drivers is empty.How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Connect to LAN. Wait for some time. Usually available drivers appear in a while.

If they dont appear after waiting, do this,

```
sudo lshw -class network
```

From the output, copy the 'product' for wireless interface.

Eg. product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n

Try downloading and installing that Driver manually.